# Visa information on B2 visa to the USA

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

My child's surname has changed and he has a new passport, but the B2 visa has his old surname. Can we travel with the two passports and the documents that show his surname change?

Answer (score 2):

According to the State Department [here](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html):

> **I changed my name. Is my U.S. visa with my old name still valid?**
>
> If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court
> ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you
> have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply
> for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel to and from
> the United States.

So it's possible, but going through immigration may take extra time as they review the documents.